# Do punctuation texts (comma, colon, pipe, semi colon, tab) need translation at the UI level?

Tags: ux-writing

If users are required to choose one of the punctuations as an input to format CSV files - is it required to translate punctuation names (comma, colon, pipe, semi colon, tab)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I'm Dutch, work in IT, have a decent proficiency in English, yet I always have to think about which of `:` and `;` is a colon and which a semi-colon.

(C'mon ... what's actually *half* about the *semi-*colon? In Dutch, we call them (literally translated) "double point" and "point comma" - nice descriptive naming. But I digress ...)

Even in English, I would not just include the punctuation names: the actual symbols are much more important.

(As an aside, CSV stands for *Comma* Separated Values. I have seen TSV (Tab Separated Values) but don't know about other abbreviations.)

Comment: Semicolon-separated “CSV” files are common in countries where the comma is the decimal separator. Nothing standard about CSV, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

I think showing the actual punctuation marks should be sufficient. We largely may not know the names of all the punctuations but they are easily understood when visualized.

For instance, When writing Four Thousand euros in figures:

- In the U.S, it's **€4,000**
- In Germany, it's **€4.000**

And this is just one of several examples where users may not necessarily know the names of the punctuations, but by visualizing them, they can decide on the one that best fits their context.